# How to generate configuration in java class from options definition

Tags: java

I wonder if there is an nice java api to generate configuration from a description of options.

Instead of generate a pojo with getter and setters on your configuration options (we always code the same thing here). I would like to describe my configuration (options of configuration) in a metadata file and then find a way to generate a Configuration java file with all options inside it.

Comment: what configuration, what options? Your question is **very** unclear.

Comment: @luk2302, any configuration ? I don't understand your unclear problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use [nuiton-config](http://nuiton-config.nuiton.org)
 which offers an maven plugin to generate java configuration class.

There is an [nice example](http://nuiton-config.nuiton.org/v/latest/nuiton-config-example/index.html) explaining how to generate you configuration.

### Example

Imagine you have a configuration with two options:
`app.login
app.password`

in a maven module

```
<groupId>org.nuiton.config</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

You can describe with configuration in a file (`src/main/config/MyConfig.ini`):

```
description = Exemple de configuration
[option login]
description = User login
key = app.login
type = string
[option password]
description = User password
key = app.password
type = string
```

then invoke the nuiton-config mojo with adding this configuration in your pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.nuiton</groupId>
  <artifactId>nuiton-config-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Do a `mvn compile`.

You can use use the generated configuration java file `org.nuiton.config.ExampleConfig`.

Comment: And you probably should disclaim that you are part of the development team of said plugin - and your answer is basically a low-quality link only answer.

Comment: I just fix urls and add link to example.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, could you remove your -1, i just fix urls. thanks.

Comment: @TonyChemit Please copy that example to your answer along with some comments  in english.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, ok I just add an example. Is is ok to you ? thanks

Comment: @luk2302, is now the response clear enough for you? If so could you please remove your -1. thanks.